# Java while loop conversion.

Tags: java

I have this method that computes taxes due for a person with a filing status of single.
But I'm having trouble trying to convert this to a for loop or using an Array instead of a while loop because this code becomes really long and nasty looking. I want to make it look pretty by simplifying the code. Any suggestions?

```
public void calculateTax()
    {
        //The constant fields for the tax rate
        final double TAXRATE_10 = 0.1;     //10%
        //This is the tax rate percent on the tax 15%
        final double TAXRATE_15PERCENT = 0.15;
        //This is the tax rate percent on the tax 25%
        final double TAXRATE_25PERCENT = 0.25;
        //This is the tax rate percent on the tax 28%
        final double TAXRATE_28PERCENT = 0.28;
        //This is the tax rate percent on the tax 33%
        final double TAXTRATE_33PERCENT = 0.33;
        //This is the tax rate percent on the tax 35%
        final double TAXRATE_35PERCENT = 0.35;

        //constant numbers for tax boundaries.
        final int NOTRICH = 8700;
        final int MIDDLECLASS = 35350;
        final int SORTOFRICH = 85650;
        final int RICH = 178650;
        final int FORSURERICH = 388350;

        //Variables for taxable income, and tax calculation.
        long taxableIncome = income - deduction -(numberOfExemption * VAlUEOFEXEMPTION);
        double cumulatedTax = 0;

        //Calculate the Tax
        while(taxableIncome != 0)
        {
            if(taxableIncome > FORSURERICH)
            {
                cumulatedTax += ((taxableIncome-FORSURERICH) * TAXRATE_35PERCENT);
                taxableIncome = (long)FORSURERICH;
            }
            else if(taxableIncome > RICH)
            {
                cumulatedTax += ((taxableIncome-RICH) * TAXTRATE_33PERCENT);
                taxableIncome = (long)RICH;
            }
            else if(taxableIncome > SORTOFRICH)
            {
                cumulatedTax += ((taxableIncome-SORTOFRICH) * TAXRATE_28PERCENT);
                taxableIncome = (long)SORTOFRICH;
            }
            else if(taxableIncome > MIDDLECLASS)
            {
                cumulatedTax += ((taxableIncome-MIDDLECLASS) * TAXRATE_25PERCENT);
                taxableIncome = (long)MIDDLECLASS;
            }
            else if(taxableIncome > NOTRICH)
            {
                cumulatedTax += ((taxableIncome-NOTRICH) * TAXRATE_15PERCENT);
                taxableIncome = (long)NOTRICH;
            }
            else
            {
                cumulatedTax += ((taxableIncome) * TAXRATE_10);
                taxableIncome = 0;
            }
        }
```

Comment: leave it as it is! it will only get more complex.

Comment: You can use java's enum. this could help you simplyfy and modularize your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the fact that your tax brackets are 1:1 coupled with your tax rates.

```
final double[][] BRACKETS = {
    {388350.0, 0.35},
    {178650.0, 0.33},
    {85650.0, 0.28},
    {35350.0, 0.25},
    {8700.0, 0.15}
};

/* ... */

for (double[] bracket: BRACKETS) {
    if(taxableIncome > bracket[0]) {
        cumulatedTax += ((taxableIncome-bracket[0]) * bracket[1]);
        taxableIncome = (long)bracket[0];
    }
}
cumulatedTax += taxableIncome * 0.1;
taxableIncome = 0;
```

If you really like C-style ALLCAPSCONSTANTS, then feel free to declare them, and just use their names instead of the literals I used in my `double[][]`. If you want to go native with Java, define a TaxBracket class. :)

*Edit*: misunderstood the intent of your code. I think my edit should do what you want.

Comment: +1: Jon Bentley recommends exactly this approach to calculating taxes by using tables in (if I recall correctly) his *More Programming Pearls* chapter on "Little Languages".

Comment: Only error I'm getting is with the taxableIncome = long(bracket[0]); unexpected token?

Comment: Woops, it should be `(long)bracket[0]`... sorry, been doing Python all day.

Comment: This is **not** right... cumulatedTax is being added `+(taxableIncome * 0.1)` for every case, and in the previous code it was not.
Just add one more line to the BRACKETS {0.0, 0.1} and should solve it.

Comment: @joaonlima I think that the original code does in fact do that... in the case where `taxableIncome > NOTRICH`, OP does `taxableIncome = (long)NOTRICH;` where this will cause the next iteration of the while loop to perform the last case. I haven't run OP's code (don't have Java installed), but I am pretty sure my code is correct. Can you explain why not? I'd be glad to fix my code if that's the case.

Comment: I think I was mistaken, sorry :)

Comment: Not a problem, I'm glad that people are looking out for mistakes!

Answer (score 12):

How about this? thinking in a more object oriented way. I did it for a few classes but you can add functionality by yourrself if you get the idea ;)

I implement it using the [Decorator Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/decorator-pattern.html).

The common interface.

```
public interface TaxCalculator {

    Double calculate(Double tax);

}
```

the base calculation for all taxes.

```
public class TaxCalculatorBase implements TaxCalculator{

    @Override
    public Double calculate(Double tax) {
        return  tax * TAXRATE_10;
    }

}
```

The decorator abstract class

```
public abstract class TaxCalculatorDecorator implements TaxCalculator{

    private final TaxCalculator decoratee;

    /**
     * @param decoratee
     */
    public TaxCalculatorDecorator(TaxCalculator decoratee) {
        super();
        this.decoratee = decoratee;
    }

    @Override
    public Double calculate(Double tax) {
        Double returnValue = decoratee.calculate(tax); 
        return taxCalculate(returnValue);
    }

    protected abstract Double taxCalculate(Double tax);


}
```

and the decorators concrete classes. I only did 2 as an example

```
public class NotRichTaxCalculator extends TaxCalculatorDecorator{

    public NotRichTaxCalculator(TaxCalculator taxCalculator) {
            super(taxCalculator);
    }

@Override
protected Double taxCalculate(Double tax) {
    return ((tax-NOTRICH) * TAXRATE_15PERCENT);
}
```

}

Sort of rich tax calculator

```
public class SortOfRichTaxCalculator extends TaxCalculatorDecorator{

    public SortOfRichTaxCalculator(TaxCalculator decoratee) {
        super(decoratee);
    }

    @Override
    protected Double taxCalculate(Double cumulatedTax) {
        return  ((cumulatedTax-SORTOFRICH) * TAXRATE_28PERCENT);;
    }



}
```

and a simple Factory to create objects

```
public final class TaxCalculatorFactory {

    private TaxCalculatorFactory(){}

    public static TaxCalculator create(Double taxableIncome){

        TaxCalculator taxCalculator= null;      

          if(taxableIncome > SORTOFRICH)
         {
             taxCalculator = new SortOfRichTaxCalculator(new NotRichTaxCalculator(new TaxCalculatorBase()));
         }else if(taxableIncome > NOTRICH)
         {
             taxCalculator = new NotRichTaxCalculator(new TaxCalculatorBase());
         }
         else
         {
             taxCalculator =new TaxCalculatorBase();
         }

        return taxCalculator;
    }
}
```

then in client code you only have to write this.

```
TaxCalculator taxCalculator= TaxCalculatorFactory.create(tax);
Double acumulatedTaxes = taxCalculator.calculate(tax);
```

Comment: Brilliant I will have to write like that for when I write more code in the future.

Answer (score 3):

I like the approaches above, but I'd encourage you to investigate using an [EnumMap](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/09/what-is-enummap-in-java-example-tutorial.html) instead of the `double[][]` in [agarrett's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/691859/agarrett) example.

Comment: I didn't know that existed... very nice! I agree wholeheartedly, but I don't want to go to the trouble of changing my answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
List<Integer> taxSlabs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
taxSlabs.put(388350); 
taxSlabs.put(178650); 
taxSlabs.put(85650); 
taxSlabs.put(35350); 
taxSlabs.put(8700); 

List<Double> taxRates = new ArrayList<Double>();
taxRates.put(0.35); 
taxRates.put(0.33); 
taxRates.put(0.28); 
taxRates.put(0.25); 
taxRates.put(0.15);


//Variables for taxable income, and tax calculation.
long taxableIncome = income - deduction -(numberOfExemption * VAlUEOFEXEMPTION);
double cumulatedTax = 0.0; 


for(int indx = 0; indx < taxSlabs.size(); indx++){
    int slabLimit = taxSlabs.get(indx).intValue(); 
    if(taxableIncome >=  slabLimit ){
        cumulatedTax += ((taxableIncome% slabLimit) * taxRates.get(indx).doubleValue());
        taxableIncome = (long)slabLimit;
    }
}
```

Comment: We just recently covered ArraysList in our class I'm familiar with this but want to make sure it works with the code above?. thanks (:

Comment: @Shire: If it doesn't work, let me know. I typed it right here so there may be some minor issues.